# PHP array_search exact match

Tags: php

I have the following array. Note that some times there are more params, sometimes there are less.

```
array(0 => 'param1: value1', 
      1 => 'param2: value2', 
      2 => 'param5: value5', 
      3 => 'param7: value7');
```

I need to put in variable the values of the params that im interested in, e.g. param1 and param7, so i decided to use array_search and then to value.

E.g.

```
$value7 = array_search('param7:', $arr1);
$avalue7 = explode(':', $arr1[$value7]);
$value7 = $aValue7[1]
```

However it does not work - array_search does not find any matches, most probably because it search for exact match. Any suggestions, or improvements are welcome.

Comment: It's a little more work, but you'll have to use a `foreach()` with a `strpos()` (or `preg_match()`) to get partial matches

Comment: Alternately, add another dimension to the array so it is more useful.  `array( 0 => array('param1' => value1));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_grep()` to search in arrays.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, im gonna check it now.

Answer (score 4):

why don't you use a associative array?

```
$arr1 = array(
    "param1" => "value1",
    "param2" => "value2",
    ...   //complete it to the desired number of params
);

echo $arr1['param7'];
```

Comment: +1 -  no need to be such a contortionist - get the data laid out in a way it is more useful.

Comment: Thanks, but what i show you is the way i got the array, cannot do much about it.